# Space and Tab characters show up weirdly in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, special-characters

Each time I hit the spacebar, it puts a dot mid line, and when I hit tab key I get an arrow which points to the right of the line.

How do I get rid of those marks?

Answer (score 2):

You have the hidden characters visible. It is either under Options or Preferences where you can change the See Hidden Characters.

Answer (score 0):

in "home" tab, click on the key shown in the image below with red circle.

[image]